# Inconsistent applying permissions

Tags: linux, macos, permissions, file-permissions

Changing permissions in a script after installing certain apps (Linux and OSX), I found the following very confusing.

Creating an ".app" in OSX requires placing a directory with a number of files (application, resources, libraries) in the /Aplications directory, with root permissions. The app could be pulled from a CD or network, which means that its permissions are really not what I need. The app will need executable permissions, and so will the libraries, while some items are ok to be just "r", not "x". I am not touching the "w" permissions - here should not be any though.

```
chmod -R +rx /Applications/myApp
```

does it perfectly, for all inner directories (and yes some items will get +x permission when they don't need them but doesn't matter).

For both Linux and OSX : I am saving (printing to file) some files in `/tmp/company/product`. So during install, I also added

```
chmod -R +rw /tmp/company
```

The result was

```
rwx r-x r-x
```

I ended up applying 777 permissions to the folder... But I just don't understand why adding the r and w permissions didn't work.

Perhaps someone can help explain ?

Btw I also did

```
chmod +rw /tmp/company
chmod +rw /tmp/company/product
```

with same effect, permissions did not apply. (On OSX it was weird, ls -l showed right permissions but Finder properties showed no permissions... and files did not get written inside directory... On linux, ls -l really showed only rx permissions for "other")

Is it special when I apply +w permission as opposed to numbers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's related to your umask. See this from the chmod manpage:

> A combination of the letters 'ugoa' controls which users' access to
>   the file will be changed: the user who owns it (u), other users in the
>   file's group (g), other users not in the file's  group  (o),  or  all
>   users (a).  If none of these are given, the effect is as if 'a' were
>   given, but bits that are set in the umask are not affected.

Based on what you described, your umask is probably 0022. So the group and other permissions are not set when you do not give chmod one of 'ugoa'. Try just using `chmod a+rw /tmp/company` instead.